# Wireless Lan: 2.4 and 5.0GHz bands into single SSID?

Tags: wifi

At the moment I do not need to set up, vlans to split traffic from different APs or bands, so I was wondering if is it a good idea to just have an SSID for all the APs, both 2.4 and 5.0 bands.

What may be the disadvantage of such a setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage is that might make it harder to know which band you're connecting to (not that you couldn't know such as after the fact, it just wouldn't be as obvious depending on what connection manager you're using to connect to WiFi networks).  As long as you don't need the extra range that 2.4ghz offers, it's nice to ensure that you're connecting to the faster 5ghz band which also has less potential interference from things like microwaves or certain non-WiFi wireless devices.

Comment: And the other way around is also a disadvantage, as [some devices](http://readwrite.com/2013/08/07/chromecast-n-wireless-wifi-5ghz-2-4ghz) don't yet support 5hgz.